# Git bash does not capture the first character I type

Tags: windows, windows-7, mingw, git-bash, mingw-w64

Often when I (re)activate the mingw-64 git bash window and start typing a shell command, the first character that I type is not captured. This results in an incorrect command, which I have to fix before I can execute it. Since I use the git bash a lot, this buggy behaviour really slows me down and frustrates me.

I cannot consistently reproduce the issue, it just occurs at random, after I haven't used the git bash for a short while. When I paste a command into the git bash window, the same may happen: i.e. the first character in the pasted command is omitted.

I'm using git version `2.6.2.windows.1` together with the mingw-64 git bash that comes with it.

I can't imagine I'm the only one with this problem. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: I only saw this error on one machine. It happened when I used ctrl+tab to navigate to the window rather than the mouse pointer. I was able to solve it by reinstalling git bash and changing the terminal emulator from minTTY to Windows Default Console Window. On my other machines I prefer the minTTY experience and have stuck with it but it was worth compromising on the Windows Default Console to get rid of the initial key stroke issue on the machine with the problem. I have not discovered why it happened on the one machine.